# Why does the random access property of iota_view depend on the element type? And how to write a Foo such that iota(Foo{1}, Foo{10}) is random-access?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, range-v3

The following code fails to compile if you uncomment the commented line. ([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bY3bvGWxr))

Why is that?

I imagine the reason is that the `iota_view` of `Foo`s doesn't know how to advance a `Foo`. But how do I make it know?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

struct Foo {
    int x;
    Foo() : x{-1} {}
    Foo(int x) : x{x} {}
    using difference_type = int;
    friend auto operator<=>(Foo const& a, Foo const& b) {
        return a.x <=> b.x;
    }
    friend bool operator==(Foo const& a, Foo const& b) {
        return a.x == b.x;
    }
    auto& operator++() {
        ++x;
        return *this;
    }
    auto operator++(int) {
        auto r = *this;
        ++x;
        return r;
    }
};

int main () {
    auto ints = std::views::iota(1, 30);
    for (auto i : ints) {}
    std::cout << ints[15] << std::endl;
    auto foos = std::views::iota(Foo{1}, Foo{30});
    for (auto i : foos) {}
    //std::cout << foos[15] << std::endl;
}
```

The example usees [std-ranges](/questions/tagged/std-ranges), but I'm interested in an answer for [range-v3](/questions/tagged/range-v3) too, should they differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view/iterator

To be a random access range, the type needs to be "advanceable". This requires `operator+`, `operator+=`, `operator-` and `operator-=` (and `operator--` to be a bidirectional range).

Advancing an iterator by `n` will just add `n` to the current value with `operator+=` or `operator+`.

Example implementations:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    // ...
    Foo& operator--() { --x; return *this; }
    Foo operator--(int) { auto r = *this; --*this; return r; }
    friend Foo operator+(Foo l, int r) { return Foo{ l.x + r }; }
    friend Foo operator+(int l, Foo r) { return Foo{ l + r.x }; }
    friend Foo operator-(Foo l, int r) { return Foo{ l.x - r }; }
    friend int operator-(Foo l, Foo r) { return l.x - r.x; }
    Foo& operator+=(int r) { return *this = *this + r; }
    Foo& operator-=(int r) { return *this = *this - r; }
};
```